# How do social media "Follow" and "Friend" functions work?

Tags: reactjs, twitter, social-networking

I've been viewing a lot of 'Twitter Clone' and 'Instagram Clone' videos but none of them go into detail on how the "Follow" functions work.

How do I show only posts by people you follow? Do you filter the API based on a 'following' Boolean attribute?

I'm just really confused how that wouldn't bog down the app.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

P.S. (I typically use JS and React)

Comment: I believe many of these apps use a graph database for those kinds of relationships

Answer (score 2):

These functionalities are implemented in the backend and not the frontend.
Imagine twitter filtering millions of tweets on your mobile to show you the ones that you follow. It is not feasible at all. All these things are done in high-performing servers and database queries depending on your choices and following.
So basically you are looking at the wrong place, you should try learning some basics of NodeJs and Mongo DB and then implement it using these.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Is it just simple filtering of the DB or more complex? I guess I'll try finding some tutorials on Node. Thanks!